# Preventing coldfusion from escaping characters

Tags: xml, encoding, coldfusion

I have a standard xml which contains a string like "test & # 3 5 ; 4"(just ignore the spaces). Now when I read it with cffile.read then this string becomes "test#4". Is there any way to prevent coldfusion to encoding characters? I already tried changing the encoding on cffile.read and it didn't work.

Comment: Could you post the actual XML, CF code, and result?  CFFile shouldn't do anything with XML entities, so I suspect something else is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to double up your hash, ie: "test & ## 3 5 ; 4" - so something like:

`replace( yourstring , "##" , "####" , "all" )`

Comment: The problem with this is that while it solves the encoding problem, when I try to parse the xml it gives me "myfile.xml is not in valid XML format"

Comment: Then you'll need to use a place holder, such as:

Before processing:
`replace( yourstring , "##" , "-hash-" , "all" )`

After processing:
`replace( yourstring , "-hash-" , "##" , "all" )`